# How to include an external library in the build of the Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

Is there a way to include an external library when building the Sphinx documentation? Specifically, I try to build the documentation on readthedocs but the Python package relies on an external Fortran library which has to be build and added to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Otherwise, some of the import statements will cause an error. Is this possible with the Sphinx configuration file?

Comment: Did you [read the docs on specifying dependencies on Read the Docs](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/specifying-dependencies.html)?

Comment: Yes but it only seems to explain how to specify any Python dependencies.